# Why is C# 3D imgae brush not working when programmatically applied to a 3d model?

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, brush

I have this really simple C# method that creates a MeshGeometry3D element and places it inside a Model
3DGroup programmatically:

```
  public static GeometryModel3D DrawElement(Model3DGroup group,string type, double x, double y)
          {
              MeshGeometry3D mesh = new MeshGeometry3D();
              mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(-0.5, -0.5, 0));
              mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(0.5, -0.5, 0));
              mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(0.5, 0.5, 0));
              mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(-0.5, 0.5, 0));

              mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);
              mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(1);
              mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);
              mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);
              mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(3);
              mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);                      


              if (type == "highlight")
              {                
                  ImageBrush imgBrush = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"E:\2.jpg")));
                  element = new GeometryModel3D(mesh, new DiffuseMaterial(imgBrush));
              }

              element.Transform = new Transform3DGroup();
              group.Children.Add(element);
              return element;
          }
```

The problem is that when I use th eimage brush the object doesn't show up, like if it's invisible, but when I use a solid brush like this, it works fine:

```
  element = new GeometryModel3D(mesh, new DiffuseMaterial(Brushes.Red));
```

I double checked and the image file E:\2.jpg exists.

Can you please help me out?

Comment: Weird check but try reversing slash `new Uri(@"E:/2.jpg")` ie: [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netframework-4.8#implicit-file-path-support)

Comment: @gen_angry Thanks but didn't work either. Thank you